# MedianCalc() method give me IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this method to get the median value,

```
public double getMedian(double[] numberList) {
        int factor = numberList.length;
        double[] first = new double[(int) factor / 2];
        double[] last = new double[first.length];
        double[] middleNumbers = new double[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            first[i] = numberList[i];
        }
        for (int i = numberList.length; i >= last.length; i--) {
            last[i] = numberList[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberList.length; i++) {
            if (numberList[i] != first[i] || numberList[i] != last[i])
                middleNumbers[i] = numberList[i];
        }
        if (numberList.length % 2 == 0) {
            double total = middleNumbers[0] + middleNumbers[1];
            return total / 2;
        } else {
            return middleNumbers[0];
        }
    }
```

but give me an **IndexOutOfBounds** Exception.
Could someone help me to fix the error?

Comment: To start, at which line do you get the exception?

Comment: at the line  last[i] = numberList[i];

Comment: BTW, please forgive me if you wrote this, but that alogrithm sucks!

Comment: Well, that line is always going to break since `i` can never be less than the length of `last`.  My advice is make sure that you understand that array indices are zero based, how to code for that and go Google for a better algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplified Answer**
If you only want [the median value](http://www.mathsisfun.com/median.html), simply use your if-else on `numberList`, there is no need for any sub-arrays:

```
public double getMedian(double[] numberList) {
    int middle = numberList.length / 2;
    if (numberList.length % 2 == 0) {
        double total = numberList[middle - 1] + numberList[middle]
        return total / 2;
    } else {
        return numberList[middle];
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**
As I stated under Zim-Zam's answer, this loop doesn't use the correct indices either:

```
for (int i = numberList.length; i >= last.length; i--) {
    last[i] = numberList[i];
}
```

`last` can only have `0` through `numberList.length / 2` (rounded down).
It looks like you want two split `numberList` into `first` and `last`, simply use:

```
int[] first = Arrays.copyOfRange(numberList, 0, factor);
int[] last = Arrays.copyOfRange(numberList, factor, numberList.length);
```

Instead of your for-loops.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `i < numberList.length`, not `i <= numberList.length;` the legal indexes of an array are `[0, array.length-1]`, i.e. `array.length` is not a legal index

Comment: Don't you mean [0, array.length-1]?

Comment: @Simon: round bracket means excluded ;)

Comment: @jlordo Huh?  In which notation?  What grammar?

Comment: This will be problematic too: `for (int i = numberList.length; i >= last.length; i--) {`

Comment: I've made the edit for you since I believe your original was confusing and people here expect to see a programming language grammar.

Comment: @Simon: check _Notations for intervals_ here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))

Comment: @jlordo  OK, you got me.  But I've still edited it to how 95% of people on here will understand it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I cannot fix this issues, I have already tried to fix with length-1 with no result, always same error. Could you rewrite a fixed version of my method?

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works.  Unless you work out (with our help) why you have an error, how to correct it and *learn* from the experience, we're not interested.  Giving you fixed code will solve nothing.